# how to set currentdate as mindate in calendar component of primefaces?

Tags: jsf-2

I am using calendar component of primefaces. I want to set `mindate=currentdate.` I want restrict user to select date before current date. I am using JSF2.0.

Comment: Yes, **<p:calendar mindate=""/>** has mindate attribute. I have get current date in backing bean like this ,                       'Calendar curr = Calendar.getInstance();
 currentdate = new java.util.Date((curr.getTime()).getTime());'          But I don't know how to write currentdate object in mindate attribute in .xhtml page.

Answer (score 22):

Just bind it as a bean property the usual way.

```
<p:calendar ... mindate="#{bean.currentDate}" />
```

By the way, the way how you created the current date is clumsy. Just invoking the `Date`'s own constructor is sufficient. Using the `Calendar` for this purpose only brings unnecessary overhead along.

```
private Date currentDate = new Date();

public Date getCurrentDate() {
    return currentDate;
}
```

Comment: It works for me on PrimeFaces 3.3. What PrimeFaces version are you using?

Comment: PrimeFaces 3.2. when mindate attribute is set? Here, actually bean.currentDate method is not called.

Comment: Should work just fine on 3.2 as well. Apparently your EL syntax or getter method signature is wrong. I've updated the answer with the correct getter method signature.

Comment: bean is:                                                                'public class adBean {

    private Date currentDate = new Date();

    /** Creates a new instance of adBean */
    public adBean() {
    }

    public Date getCurrentDate() {
        System.out.print("currDate............"+currentDate);
        return currentDate;
    }


}                                                                      <p:calendar mode="popup" showOn="both" mindate="#{adBean.currentDate}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" effect="fadeIn"/>'

Comment: Looks fine. Apparently `#{adBean}` simply doesn't exist. Make sure that it is properly registered as managed bean and available in EL scope.

Comment: It is registered. Can I get currentdate in EL without using bean?

Comment: What do you see in `<h:outputText value="#{adBean.currentDate}" />`?

Comment: No. Can I get today's date from calendar control of primefaces?

Comment: If you don't see that in a simple output text, then the `#{adBean}` simply doesn't exist. Your bean is not properly registered. You should have `@ManagedBean @RequestScoped` annotations from `javax.faces.bean` package on it and the class name must be `public class AdBean` and not `public class adBean`.

Comment: I get it. Now I want that current date is also be disable. means mindate=currentdate+1day. What should I do?

Comment: Just add 1 day to it. Press `Ask Question` if you can't figure it out, this is offtopic.

Comment: As said, this is offtopic. Your initial question has already been answered. You should not ask new questions in comments of existing questions. Press `Ask Question`.

Comment: The PF showcase somehow hints the argument for mindate and maxdate is of type string, but as described a `Date` object works fine.

Comment: Wouldn't @Future work ? I've no IDE on me to try it out

Answer (score 15):

```
<p:calendar mindate="today">
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this,

```
 <p:calendar mindate="calwidget.today()" widgetVar="calwidget" value="#{bean.date}">
```

Comment: has a problem: if you open repeatedly the calendar and picks a new date, the today() function will going to recalculate accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using omnifaces, you can do this:

```
<p:calendar ... mindate="#{now}" />
```